# What's going on with Apple Numbers dates?

Tags: macos, numbers

I have an Apple Numbers table that I've been updating since 2016. At the start, I incorrectly inputted dates such as `1-1-2009` as `1-1-9`. (This is not a problem for later dates such as `1-1-10` because Numbers will interpret that as `1-1-2010`.) In 2018, I manually corrected this to `1-1-2009`.

Now, when I go back via Time Machine to versions with the incorrect dates, a date like `1-1-9` has changed to `3-1-9`. So every incorrect date has two days added!

Fun fact: inside the `.numbers` bundle, there a `preview.jpg` that is created when the file is saved. The dates visible on there are *correct*. So clearly, the `1-1-9` remained that way when the file was saved. It even was still that way when I corrected the dates in 2018. But at some point between 2018 and now, the incorrect dates have changed by two days.

Can anyone explain this plus-two day change?